# Oracle APEX SQL Date Time Import Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a field (v_date) that contains date and time value e.g.(30-07-2021 13:30)
I want to import to my table two new dates and time values according to this field.
The first will be seven days later (08-06-2021 13:30), and the second one will be 7 days and one hour later (08-06-2021 14:30).

This is my code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "PR_ADD_MASSIVE_SESSIONS"
(v_date date)
IS
v_counter_day number :=7;
v_session_temp_date date;
v_session_temp_end date;


BEGIN

v_session_temp_date := to_date(v_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI') + v_counter_day;
v_session_temp_end := to_date(v_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI') + (v_counter_day + (1/1440*60));
        
INSERT INTO SESSIONS (CLIENTS_ID, SESSION_AREA, SESSION_DATE, SESSION_STOP, PAYMENT_TYPE_ID, PRICE, STATUS, COMPLETED, PAYMENT_STATUS, SESSION_NO)
VALUES (5, 1, v_session_temp_date, v_session_temp_end, 2, 40, 1, 1, 1, 1);

END;
```

And I get this error: Ajax call returned server error ORA-01843: not a valid month.
I try with to_char but the compiler only wants to_date in order to have a successful procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables v_session_temp_date and v_session_temp_date are defined as `DATE`. The function `TO_DATE` converts a *string* to a date. It should not be used on variables of type `DATE`. Remove the `TO_DATE` and you're good to go. Example code below (using an anonymous block, not a procedure)

```
CREATE TABLE sessions
(
clients_id NUMBER,
session_area NUMBER,
session_date  DATE,
session_stop  DATE,
payment_type_id NUMBER,
price NUMBER,
status NUMBER,
completed NUMBER,
payment_status NUMBER,
session_no NUMBER
);

Table SESSIONS created.

--original code
DECLARE
  v_date date := SYSDATE;
  v_counter_day number := 7;
  v_session_temp_date date;
  v_session_temp_end date;
BEGIN
  v_session_temp_date := to_date(v_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI') + v_counter_day;
  v_session_temp_end := to_date(v_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI') + (v_counter_day + (1/1440*60));
  
  INSERT INTO SESSIONS (CLIENTS_ID, SESSION_AREA, SESSION_DATE, SESSION_STOP, PAYMENT_TYPE_ID, PRICE, STATUS, COMPLETED, PAYMENT_STATUS, SESSION_NO)
  VALUES (5, 1, v_session_temp_date, v_session_temp_end, 2, 40, 1, 1, 1, 1);
END;
/
ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at line 7
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:

--fixed code
DECLARE
  v_date date := SYSDATE;
  v_counter_day number := 7;
  v_session_temp_date date;
  v_session_temp_end date;
BEGIN
  v_session_temp_date := v_date + v_counter_day;
  v_session_temp_end := v_date + (v_counter_day + (1/1440*60));
  
  INSERT INTO SESSIONS (CLIENTS_ID, SESSION_AREA, SESSION_DATE, SESSION_STOP, PAYMENT_TYPE_ID, PRICE, STATUS, COMPLETED, PAYMENT_STATUS, SESSION_NO)
  VALUES (5, 1, v_session_temp_date, v_session_temp_end, 2, 40, 1, 1, 1, 1);
END;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Hi @Koen and thank you for your answer. When i save this procedure i do have PL/SQL code successfully compiled, but when i run this procedure i get this error :Ajax call returned server error ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: Ah.... you're invoking this procedure in an apex page right ? With v_date passed as an argument from the page ? Note that apex is a web application, it has no notion of oracle data types. It will pass a string whereas the procedure is expecting a date and doing an internal conversion based on the session nls settings. You're better off using a VARCHAR2 type for your procedure parameter and doing the conversion to date in the procedure itself.

Comment: You're right!! I followed your instructions and it works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: glad to be of help :)